# Cannot load material design css from CDN using Firebase Hosting

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, cors, material-design, firebase-hosting

I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://nhalistonfirebase.firebaseapp.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

[image: screenshot]

Here's my firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    // Add the "headers" section within "hosting".
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=7200"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How should this be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`code.getmdl.io` doesn’t send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header that’s necessary to make browsers allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

The `firebase.json` file shown in the question is for the https://nhalistonfirebase.firebaseapp.com site I guess? If so, it doesn’t matter what CORS config you do there—what instead matters is what CORS config is set on the site your code is sending the request to.

And the `code.getmdl.io` site apparently has no CORS config to allow cross-origin requests.

But you can get around this by using a CORS proxy. You can instead use this request URL:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css
```

That sends the request through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, which forwards the request to `https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css` and then receives the response. The `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` backend adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response and passes that back to your requesting frontend code.

The browser will then allow your frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

You can also easily set up your own CORS proxy using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

Comment: Wouldn't the proxy advert the benefit of CDN?

Comment: Yeah I guess putting a proxy in between would reduce the benefit of using a CDN, but if you have no other option than needing to use the CDN to begin with, at least it makes it possible to get it to work with your frontend code